# SQL IN operator with subquery returns false, but it should be true

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have some data in Snowflake and I'm using web interface to run some queries.

I have the following query:

```
select * from MY_TABLE
where AIRPORT_CODE in (select IATA from AIRPORT_CODES_TABLE)
```

This returns an empty result. However, there are values in `MY_TABLE` which should be returned.

If I just create the following testing query, I actually do get some of the results back:

```
select * from MY_TABLE
where AIRPORT_CODE in ('YHZ')
```

So there are clearly rows in `MY_TABLE` which have a value of `'YHZ'`. And also, `YHZ` is definitely in the table `AIRPORT_CODES_TABLE` , so the original query should return some results as well. Here is a snippet of `AIRPORT_CODES_TABLE`:

```
select IATA from AIRPORT_CODES_TABLE
```

[image: Table picture of YHZ in the AIRPORT_CODES_TABLE]

What am I missing here? I referred to [the official docs](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/operators-subquery.html#not-in-subqueries) to make my queries, so it should be correct.

Comment: Trailing spaces? Try `select IATA from AIRPORT_CODES_TABLE where IATA in ('YHZ')`

Comment: Does this return anything? `select * from AIRPORT_CODES_TABLE
where IATA in ('YHZ')`

Comment: Those queries returned nothing. So it is trailing spaces. Thanks guys; that's a good idea.

Comment: @MichaelYaworski FYI, this is a excellent reason why surrogate keys (I prefer integer columns) are used instead of natural keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just a thought can you try by using `Trim`   function

```
SELECT *
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE Trim(AIRPORT_CODE) IN (
    SELECT Trim(IATA)
    FROM AIRPORT_CODES_TABLE
    )
```

Comment: I had to call `trim(IATA)` like you showed because apparently the IATA values have exactly 3 trailing spaces